# faster way of constructing array of arrays

Tags: python

I have a two long list `x` and `y` containing around 1000 elements with numbers as big as `~10^6`. I am constructing `1000x1000` array of arrays with list comprehension which I am using as matrix.

```
m = [[f(x[i], y[j]) for i in range(1000)] for j in range(1000)]
```

where `f(x,y)` is some function that returns fraction of x and y. Let's say `Fraction[x,y]`. I am generating 1000 random numbers from 0-10^6 in the list `x` and `y`.  The execution time is 15.8269999027 seconds.

Are there any data structures that allows me to construct this matrix under 1s? Later I have to use this to find the LU decomposition of this matrix (I have to code for it) and I don't have any libraries available.

Comment: If you really need to construct that matrix, then there may not be anything faster. But it depends on what you really want to do with the matrix.

Comment: If you're on python 2, start by using `xrange` instead of `range`. Also, can you use `numpy`?

Comment: It seems almost all of that time must be taken up with the million calls to `f()`. How could we guess how to improve the execution time of your `f()`?

Comment: @AnandSKumar Find the LU decomposition first. Later I have other algorithms relating to GCD. All must be done under 10s, but this alone takes 15 seconds.

Comment: @juanchopanza no .. everything is hard coded :(

Comment: How are you generating `x` and `y`? How are you timing your code?

Comment: @DanGetz it doesn't make difference. f() returns fraction of x and y, let's say x/y.

Comment: And with that code your method takes 16 seconds? I'm skeptical.

Comment: I have no idea what "hard coded" means in this context. So, use `xrange` if using python 2, and look into `numpy`.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Inputting from out file http://pastebin.com/GbRDGiNs

Comment: @juanchopanza numpy scipy any other library are not available :(

Comment: I have no idea why you pasted a bunch of numbers in the pastebin; what I asked was how are you generating the list `x` and the list `y`; and how you are timing your code.

Comment: @DanGetz check this out http://imgur.com/VBv2p23 and http://i.imgur.com/VBv2p23.png

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I am constructing `x` and `y` using those numbers. I am inputting them with `x = map(int, raw_input().split(' '))` from out file. http://i.imgur.com/VBv2p23.png

Comment: Can you explain a bit where this question (and the peculiar restrictions) are coming from?  Doing matrix operations in Python without using NumPy is a bit like coding with both hands tied behind your back.

Comment: @dread_cat_pirate that's timing the entire run of your script, not the line your question asks about. Why not [edit] your question to include your code?

Comment: Instead of drip feeding us information; post your `main.py` script.

Comment: @dread_cat_pirate: In that case, I strongly suspect that you're going about this in the wrong way.  Look for a solution that *doesn't* involve doing LU decomposition on a 1000x1000 matrix.

Comment: @dread_cat_pirate there is an [edit] link under your question. Put relevant code in the question, not comments.

Comment: @MarkDickinson it doesn't actually I only have to calculate the determinant. which takes around 5 min :( I guess there is not solution that can be done under 10 seconds.

Comment: @dread_cat_pirate: Okay, but that's going to take a long time too.  Still sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info) to me.

Comment: @MarkDickinson let me know if you visited the link I just posted.

Comment: @dread_cat_pirate: What's the *actual* problem you need to solve?  I don't see a link to that anywhere.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Yes, you're right: you shouldn't be doing this. :-)

Comment: @MarkDickinson I already solved this, 2/4 test cases pass, the last 3rd and 4th test case fails because they are huge, and I wanted to optimize it. It should be done under 10secods, my code takes IDK how many minutes.

Comment: @MarkDickinson let me know your thoughts if this problem can be solved under 10s using python. I think, it can't be ... if possible please post solution after 10 hrs when it ends.

Answer (score 1):

The runtime is dominated by the function, so there isn't any way to get around that. I can show you with an example:

```
import random
import time

def randlist():
  return [random.randint(0, 10**6) for x in xrange(1000)]

def f(x, y):
  return x / y

random.seed(0)
x = randlist()
y = randlist()

# The code we want to optimize
start = time.time()
m = [[f(x[i], y[j]) for i in range(1000)] for j in range(1000)]
end = time.time()
print end - start

# Measuring the function invocations without creating the matrix at all
start = time.time()
for i in xrange(1000):
  for j in xrange(1000):
    f(x[i], y[j]) 
end = time.time()
print end - start
```

On my computer, creating the matrix takes 0.24s while running the function 1 million times takes 0.21s. So no matter how you build the matrix, you will only be able to save ~0.03s.

Comment: This takes 13 seconds http://pastebin.com/GVNSEkav I think fraction is taking long time.